Problems of using Ubuntu 22.04.4 with intel Ultra 7 155H
My laptop is thinkbook 16+, intel Ultra 7 155H. I used the desktop ISO to install Ubuntu 22.04.4 for use. My touchpad is now not working. Meanwhile, Ubuntu fails to detect the Integrated graphic in Ultra 7 and I cannot adjust the brightness of my screen.
